# Difference of inverse squares

Tags: natural-numbers

Given that the positive number $a$ is the difference of inverse squares:

$$a = \frac{1}{n^2} - \frac{1}{m^2}, m, n \in \mathbb{N},$$

could it well be that the $pa$ is also a difference of inverse squares , when p - some natural number ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes 
$1/(5*5)-1/(7*7)=24/(25*49)$
$1/(5*5)-1/(35*35)=48/(25*49)$
so we have $2*((1/5)^2-(1/7)^2)=(1/5)^2-(1/35)^2$ 
 But it very interesting to see formula (I've made program to get this answer)

Comment: @Galc127 , for numbers less that 100 my program had found more that 20 solutions .

Comment: do you mind to share your thoughts?

Comment: 5 7 5 35  ;          
5 10 4 20 ;           
6 10 5 15 ;          
9 11 11 99  ;    
10 14 10 70  ;                
5 15 3 5.   This is first 6 answers in format (m,n,k,p) where $2(1/(m*m)-1/(n*n))=1/(k*k)-1/(p*p)$ . But I have no idea how to get formula

Answer (score 1):

If

$$a = \frac{1}{n^2} - \frac{1}{m^2},$$

where $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ is the set of natural numbers, then

$$2a = \frac{2}{n^2} - \frac{2}{m^2}.$$

The OP is asking for solutions to the Diophantine equation

$$2a = \frac{2}{n^2} - \frac{2}{m^2} = \frac{1}{r^2} - \frac{1}{s^2},$$

where $r, s \in \mathbb{N}$.

This reduces to

$$2{r^2}{s^2}(m + n)(m - n) = {m^2}{n^2}(r + s)(r - s).$$

Consequently, we have:

$$2{r^2}{s^2} \mid {m^2}{n^2}(r + s)(r - s).$$

Assuming $\gcd(r, s) = 1$, then we have either:

> > (1) $2 \mid m$, or
> >
> > (2) $2 \mid n$, or
> >
> > (3) $2{r^2}{s^2} \mid {m^2}{n^2}$, or
> >
> > (4) $2 \mid (r + s)(r - s)$.

Perhaps this could shed some light into [Antony](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/180827)'s answer.

Update - Antony gave the following solutions:

$$n  \hspace{0.1in} m  \hspace{0.1in}  r  \hspace{0.1in} s$$
$$5  \hspace{0.1in} 7  \hspace{0.1in}  5  \hspace{0.1in} 35$$
$$5  \hspace{0.1in} 10 \hspace{0.1in}  4  \hspace{0.1in} 20$$ 
$$6  \hspace{0.1in} 10 \hspace{0.1in}  5  \hspace{0.1in} 15$$
$$9  \hspace{0.1in} 11 \hspace{0.1in}  11 \hspace{0.1in} 99$$
$$10 \hspace{0.1in} 14 \hspace{0.1in}  10 \hspace{0.1in} 70$$
$$5  \hspace{0.1in} 15 \hspace{0.1in}  3  \hspace{0.1in} 5$$

Notice that all the known solutions (so far) satisfy:

> > (4) $2 \mid (r + s)(r - s)$.

Comment: I don't understand why $2rs(m+n)(m-n)=mn(r+s)(r-s)$, shouldn't be $2r^2s^2(m+n)(m-n)=m^2n^2(r+s)(r-s)$?

Comment: Bummer, yeah you're right Galc127.  Editing my post now.

Answer (score 0):

$2a=1/(n/\sqrt{2})^2-1/(m/\sqrt{2})^2$, but $(n/\sqrt{2}) ,(m/\sqrt{2})$ won't be natural

Comment: The numbers in the denominator of the second fraction must also be too natural.

Comment: The mistake you made was to use the same $n$ and $m$ for your reasonning...